# Can't get array from a nested promise functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Trying to return a list of disk folder, then for each folder get the files in it. I want the result set to be a single array of objects.  The final output from the function call to getPosts() is a promise with an empty array.

```
Promise { [] }
```

```
  var accountId = req.body.accountId;

  var accountFilePath = 'accountFiles/' + accountId;

  function getPosts(accountFilePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let postArray = [];
      fs.readdir(accountFilePath, (err, posts) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
          var postId = posts[i];
          var postFilePath = accountFilePath + '/' + postId;
          var postObject = getFiles(postId, postFilePath)
          postObject.then((response) => {
            postArray.push(response)
          })
        }
      });
      resolve(postArray)
    })
  }

  function getFiles(postId, postFilePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readdir(postFilePath, function (err, files) {
        postObject = {
          [postId]: files
        }
        resolve(postObject)
      });
    })
  }

  var fullPostArray = getPosts(accountFilePath)
  console.log(fullPostArray);
```

Desired Result:

```
[
  {
    'folder1': [
      'DSC0366.jpg',
      'DSC8874.jpg',
      'DSC8878.jpg',
      'DSC8951.jpg'
    ]
  },
  {
    folder2: [
      'nikki.jpg',
      'richard.jpg',
      'billy.jpg'
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Reopened as the OP seems to be aware of asynchrony, he is just unable to work with multiple promises.

Comment: `readdir` is asynchronous, therefore it's callback will be called AFTER you `resolve(postArray)`

Answer (score 0):

Promise were invented to tackle the so called callback hell: Multiple asynchronous callbacks firing at different times, making it hard to keep things in order. While you tried to utilize promises you ised them at the wrong level: You still have various asynchronous things going on *inside* the promise, and that makes things complicated (and they go wrong). Instead, try to wrap the smallest asynchronous tasks into promises, in your case that would be (1) reading a folder, (2) getFiles (which you already did):

```
  function readFiles(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
       if(err) reject(err) else resolve(files);
     });
   });
 }
```

Now getPosts can be written as a chain of promising tasks, and you can use `Promise.all` to turn an array of promises into one promise:

```
  function getPosts(accountFilePath) {
    return readFiles(accountFilePath).then(posts => { // ¹
     return Promise.all(posts.map(postId => { // ²
       var postFilePath = accountFilePath + '/' + postId;
       return getFiles(postId, postFilePath); // ³
    }));
   });      
  }
```

¹: First the files are read, and *then* the next task is done. If you return a Promise from a .then callback (like in this case) that promise will also be chained.

²: Every post can then be mapped to a Promise (³) that resolves to the desired result, by using `Promise.all` on that the promise chain results in an array of results.

---

The newer `async` / `await` syntax makes that way easier (although the logic stays exactly the same):

```
 async function getPosts(accountFilePath) {
  const posts = await readFiles(accountFilePath);
  const result = await Promise.all(posts.map(postId => {
    const postFilePath = accountFilePath + '/' + postId;
    return getFiles(postId, postFilePath);
  }));
  return result;
}
```